# Is it possible to programmatically change the name of an iPhone app once it's installed on a device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm curious - is it possible to programmatically change the name of an iPhone app that is used on the iPhone OS home screen? I know it's just an entry in the Info.plist file, but I haven't seen any apps doing it.

I'd like to distribute a "Lite" version of an existing app and allow users to upgrade to the full version via in-app purchase. However, once they purchase the app, I'd like to change the app's icon and name to read "Layers Pro" instead of "Layers Lite." I feel like this is important to maintain consistency and a good upgrade experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The Info.plist and everything in the app bundle is read-only once it's installed on an iPhone.

Comment: Then is it possible to change its name before installation but after the project is created?

Comment: The application has a digital signature. To change the app bundle in any way requires a new digital signature. This means a separate application submitted for approval to the iTunes App Store.

Comment: I mean if I created a project called "AudioPlayerTest" and later on I want to change its name to "AudioPlayer". Is that possible?

Comment: Well, yeah you can change it before compile time. The original question was about changing it dynamically at runtime.

If you want to change your project name after creating it, you can just modify the "Product Name" build setting in the target settings.  Also, it doesn't hurt to rename the project file itself in the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The only way to change the name of an iPhone app is when you update the app through iTunesConnect.