# Change app name programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, plist

***I want to change the app name based on the app language selected by the user & not the system language.***

Is there any solution?

***Even if it is doable using private API, I would like to know.***

*I know there is only one way using plist but as it is read only, I won't be able to update the plist file.*

### *VImp Note, I want to change as per app language and not as per system language.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616650/how-to-make-ios-app-name-localizable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977491/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-change-the-name-of-an-iphone-app-once-its-in

Answer (score 2):

You can localize your Info.plist file.

Just select Info.plist file,and in File Inspector,click Localize... button in the Localization section.

Comment: that will go with System language and not with my app language... isn't it?

Comment: Sorry,I thought the language you mentioned is `System Language`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change your apps name programmatically.Because the name is stored in the `info.pist` which resides in you apps main bundle is read only you can not change it. You only option is to use the localized functionality provided by iOS based on the system language.

Comment: I know that and had mentioned in my question. There is no other private API or anything? Any alternate that would Apple reject is also fine...

Comment: Well no, you might be abel to change the write flag on jailbroke devices but no other clue on how to get this working.

Comment: Thanks... Big NO for  jailbroken... I wanted to get it done on the apps that I have on app store... I will email Apple and see what they reply...

Comment: @FahimParkar I want to do the same functionality in my app. any luck with Apple reply?

Comment: @RajTandel : You can't